# NodeJS and Electron - request-promise in back-end freezes CSS animation in front-end

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

*Note: Additional information appended to end of original question as **Edit #1**, detailing how `request-promise` in the back-end is causing the UI freeze. Keep in mind that a pure CSS animation is hanging temporarily, and you can probably just skip to the edit (or read all for completeness)*

**The setup**

I'm working on a desktop webapp, using [Electron](https://electronjs.org/docs).

At one point, the user is required to enter and submit some data. When they click "submit", I use JS to show [this css loading animation](https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/) (bottom-right loader), and send data asynchronously to the back-end...

*- HTML -*

```
<button id="submitBtn" type="submit" disabled="true">Go!</button>

<div class="submit-loader">
    <div class="loader _hide"></div>
</div>
```

*- JS -*

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    loader.classList.remove('_hide');

    setTimeout(function() {
        ipcRenderer.send('credentials:submit', credentials);
    }, 0)
});
```

where `._hide` is simply

```
._hide {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

and where `ipcRenderer.send()` is an [async method](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-arg1-arg2-), without option to set otherwise.

**The problem**

*Normally*, the `0ms` delay is sufficient to allow the DOM to be changed before the blocking event takes place. But not here. Whether using the `setTimeout()` or not, there is still a delay.

So, add a tiny delay...

```
loader.classList.remove('_hide');

setTimeout(function() {
    ipcRenderer.send('credentials:submit', credentials);
}, 100);
```

Great! The loader displays immediately upon submitting! But... after 100ms, the animation stops dead in its tracks, for about 500ms or so, and then gets back to chooching.

This working -> not working -> working pattern happens regardless of the delay length. As soon as the `ipcRenderer` starts doing stuff, everything is halted.

**So... Why!?**

This is the first time I've seen this kind of behavior. I'm pretty well-versed in HTML/CSS/JS, but am admittedly new to NodeJS and Electron. Why is my *pure CSS* animation being halted by the `ipcRenderer`, and what can I do to remedy this?

**Edit #1 - Additional Info**

In the back-end (NodeJS), I am using [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) to make a call to an external API. This happens when the back-end receives the `ipcRenderer` message.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

ipcMain.on('credentials:submit', function(e, credentials) {    

    var options = {
        headers : {
            ... api-key...
        },
        json: true,
        url : url,
        method : 'GET'
    };

    return rp(options).then(function(data) {
        ... send response to callback...
    }).catch(function(err) {
        ... send error to callback...
    });

}
```

The buggy freezing behavior *only happens on the first API call*. Successive API calls (i.e. refreshing the desktop app without restarting the NodeJS backend), do not cause the hang-up. Even if I call a different API method, there are no issues.

For now, I've implemented the following hacky workaround:

First, initialize the first `BrowserWindow` with `show:false`...

```
window = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false
});
```

When the window is ready, send a ping to the external API, and only display the window after a successful response...

```
window.on('ready-to-show', function() {
    apiWrapper.ping(function(response) {
        if(response.error) {
            app.quit();
        }else {
            window.show(true);
        }
    });
});
```

This extra step means that there is about 500ms delay before the window appears, but then all successive API calls (whether `.ping()` or otherwise) no longer block the UI. We're getting to the verge of [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/), but this isn't too bad.

So... this is a `request-promise` issue (which is *asynchronous*, as far as I can tell from the docs). Not sure why this behavior is only showing-up on the ***first call***, so please feel free to let me know if you know! Otherwise, the little hacky bit will have to do for now.

*(Note: I'm the only person who will ever use this desktop app, so I'm not too worried about displaying a "ping failed" message. For a commercial release, I would alert the user to a failed API call.)*

Comment: I had a similar issue. This fixed it in my case https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1854#issuecomment-167606793

Comment: @Vector I'm not sure I'm seeing it. By all accounts, the code is exactly how I was handling it (with `ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain`). I've added an edit to the original question, as it seems that the issue is with `request-proimise`

Comment: you can try other modules like axios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worth to check how does request-promise internally setups up module loading. reading it, it seems like there is kind of lazy loading (https://github.com/request/request-promise/blob/master/lib/rp.js#L10-L12) when request is being called. Quick try out

```
const convertHrtime = require('convert-hrtime');

const a = require('request-promise');

const start = process.hrtime();
a({uri: 'https://requestb.in/17on4me1'});
const end = process.hrtime(start);
console.log(convertHrtime(end));

const start2 = process.hrtime();
a({uri: 'https://requestb.in/17on4me1'});
const end2 = process.hrtime(start2);
console.log(convertHrtime(end2));
```

returns value like below:

```
{ seconds: 0.00421092,
  milliseconds: 4.21092,
  nanoseconds: 4210920 }
{ seconds: 0.000511664,
  milliseconds: 0.511664,
  nanoseconds: 511664 }
```

first call is obviously taking longer than subsequent. (number of course may vary, I ran this on bare node.js on relatively fast cpu) If module loading is major cost for first call, then it'll block main process until module is loaded (cause node.js `require` resolve is synchronous)

I'm not able to say this is concrete reason, but worth to check. As suggested in comment, try other lib or bare internal module (like Electron's `net`) to rule out.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comb through the code and test this. Without any configuration options, I think my hacky workaround is going to be my best bet. I'd look into other libraries, but it would not be an insignificant amount of time to convert all the API wrappers I have to it. Next time, I'll definitely do some unit-testing before I go too far.